# How can I count the frequency of string by another column value in a dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, frequency

A simplification of the dataframe which I'm working is:

```
> df1
         Any              nomMun
   1     2010             CADAQUES
   2     2011             CADAQUES
   3     2012             CADAQUES
   4     2010             BEGUR
   5     2011             BEGUR
   6     2012             BEGUR
```

I've been reading some post and found that count of plyr library returns a dataframe with the strings and it's frequency. But I want the frequency by year. The final result I want to obtain is a dataframe like:

```
> df2
         nomMun       freq_2010     freq_2011     freq_2012
   1     CADAQUES         1             1             1
   2     BEGUR            1             1             1
```

Could anyone you help me?

Sorry if my explanation is bad... i'm non-native speaker and it's my first time asking here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In data.table, simply use `.N`:

```
setDT(df1)
df1[, .N, .(nomMun, Any)]
```

This will give you the data in long format. In other words, it will look like:

```
Any      nomMum      N
2010     CADAQUES    1
2011     CADAQUES    1
2012     CADAQUES    1
2010     BEGUR       1
2011     BEGUR       1
2012     BEGUR       1
```

But then you can dcast it if you'd like:

```
dcast(df1[, .N, .(nomMun, Any)], nomMum ~ Any, value.var = "N")
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems silly to load a package when base R includes the `table` function.

```
> table(df1)
      nomMun
Any    BEGUR CADAQUES
  2010     1        1
  2011     1        1
  2012     1        1
```

Answer (score 0):

`tidyr::spread` can be used to get the desired output:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(nomMun, Any) %>%
  mutate(freq = n()) %>%
  spread(Any, freq)

# # A tibble: 2 x 4
# # Groups: nomMun [2]
#    nomMun   `2010` `2011` `2012`
# *  <chr>     <int>  <int>  <int>
# 1 BEGUR         1      1      1
# 2 CADAQUES      1      1      1
```